# Does the linear transformation that a matrix encodes depend on a choice of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

#### Context

Let $M$ be an $m \times n$ matrix of real numbers. Let $\mathbf{x}$ be column vector of length $n$ with elements $x_1, \ldots , x_n \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\vec{x} = (x_1, \ldots , x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be its analogue in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $\vec{\mathbf{e}}^t$ denote the **standard basis** in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that

$$
\vec{\mathbf{e}} = 
\left[
\begin{array}
.\vec{e_1} \\
\vec{e_2} \\
\vdots \\
\vec{e_n}
\end{array}
\right]
$$

and let $\vec{\mathbf{b}}^t$ denote a **non-standard** basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with

$$
\vec{\mathbf{b}} = 
\left[
\begin{array}
.\vec{b_1} \\
\vec{b_2} \\
\vdots \\
\vec{b_n}
\end{array}
\right]
$$

**Fact from Linear Algebra:** $M$ encodes a linear transformation $T:  \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that

$$
M \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{y}
$$

where $\mathbf{\vec{e}}^t M \mathbf{x} = T(\vec{x}) = \vec{y}$ is some vector in $\mathbf{R}^m$.

---

#### Question

Does the linear transformation $T$ that $M$ corresponds to depend on our choice of basis? That is, if instead of working with  $\mathbf{\vec{e}}^t$  we instead worked with $\mathbf{\vec{b}}^t$, would $M$ encode a different linear transformation? For example, if

$$
\mathbf{\vec{e}}^t \mathbf{x} = \vec{x} = \mathbf{\vec{b}}^t \mathbf{x'}
$$

then do we have that

$$
\mathbf{\vec{e}}^t M \mathbf{x} = T(\vec{x}) = \mathbf{\vec{b}}^t M \mathbf{x'}?
$$

#### EDIT

Ok. Upon reflection, it is obvious that our choice of basis matters significantly. For example, let us work in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let our non-standard basis be $(1,1)$ and $(1, -1)$.

Then the identity matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

will now send $(1,0)$ to $(1,1)$ since

$$
\begin{bmatrix} (1, 1) & (1, -1) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \left[
\begin{array}
& 1 \\
0
\end{array}
\right] = (1,1)
$$

which is clearly a different mapping than the identity mapping that would result were we to use the standard basis (where $(1, 0) \mapsto (1,0)$).

Comment: I think you are confused about some things. When we talk about how a matrix encodes a linear transformation, we need to represent both the input and output vectors using the specified basis. You seem to want to encode just one of them. If you do it correctly, you will find that indeed a given matrix encodes different transformations in different bases, but scalar matrices (such as the identity matrix you've given as an example) are special in that they encode the same transformation in any base.

Comment: Ok. But how is my computation not encoding both the input and the output with the non standard basis?

Comment: In your example you are trying to find what the vector $(1,0)$ is mapped to. To this end you are multiplying the matrix by $(1,0)$, which is wrong. You need to multiply the matrix by the representation of that vector in your chosen base. The representation is $(1/2,1/2)$ so you multiply by that, and get the representation of the output vector. Then you multiply from the left with the matrix that has the basis vectors as columns, and you get the output vector. The result will be $(1,0)$, because the identity matrix always represents the identity transformation.

Comment: Taking a cue from another answerer, I take back my statement that you *need* to use the same basis. The derivation of what you should do if you choose to use the same basis stands, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going strictly by the definitions, yes: the matrix $M$ does not necessarily encode a transformation with respect to any one basis, and as such it can encode several different transformations depending on one's choice of basis.

That being said: when a basis isn't specified, the tacit assumption is that $M$ encodes the transformation $T:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ given by $T(x) = Mx$, with respect to the standard basis.  So, if you mean something *other* than this specific transformation, you should say so.

Comment: I added an edit  to my post above which shows an example as to why the basis matters. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the right idea.  Even if you use the same (non-standard) basis for the inputs as you use for the outputs, you could get something that looks very different.

Comment: There's a comment above that suggests that my computation from going from (1,0) to (1,1) is incorrect. Is that indeed the case?

Comment: It depends on the context.  In many situations (especially with square matrices), it is useful to demand that we use the same basis on the "input space" as in the "output space", thus in many situations those are the only changes of basis we discuss.  The commenter is thinking about the situation in which we use the basis $\{(1,1),(1,-1)\}$ for *both* sides, which indeed disagrees with your computation.

Comment: OK I see,, but if in this instance we DO NOT choose to use the same basis for both sides, my computation is correct, right? If so, it establishes that the identity matrix may not denote the identity transform. To check my understanding, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @user1770201: Omnomnomnom is right, you *can* use different bases for the input and output, and in fact you have to do that if the input and output spaces are different. But in your example you've just said that we are working in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the basis is $\{(1,1),(1,-1)\}$, without separately specifying the input space and basis and the output space and basis. With such phrasing, the only reasonable interpretation is that this basis is used to represent both the input and output, and this interpretation disagrees with your calculation.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld in the "context" earlier in the question, he specifies that he's applying the standard basis to the input space and the non-standard basis to the output space.

Comment: You're right, I was wrong. The notion that the identity matrix represents a non-identity transformation seemed so outrageous to me that I assumed the OP was just being confused and not using the correct notation to describe what he's thinking about. I didn't stop to think that he's actually describing a legitimate scenario, which just happens to result in a somewhat unusual example.

Comment: Note there's a cost to doing that, which is that you can no longer compose linear transformations by multiplying together the matrices that represent them. $((1, 0), (0, 1))$ *is* the identity for 2x2 matrix multiplication, so if you want to use it to represent something other than the identity transformation then it's your sovereign right to choose notation, but it may not always be a *convenient* choice of notation. Instead the identity is the inverse of $\mathbf{\vec{b}}^t$, and the composition operator on the group of non-signular matrices is some fiddly thing.

Comment: (this may be the source of Meni's outrage)

Answer (score 6):

A matrix, in the context you are looking at, is a representation of a linear map with respect to a choice of basis, both in source and target.

If you want the same map but want to use another basis, you have to transform the matrix, too. Textbooks on linear algebra will tell you how.

Put from the other point of view: if you fix the matrix $M$ but change the basis, you'll get a different map.

Comment: I added an edit  to my post above which shows an example as to why the basis matters. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the choice of basis makes a difference. For this reason, some books will write something like the following: If $T$ is a linear transformation, then the matrix representation of $T$ relative to a basis $\beta = \{\beta_1, \beta_2,...,\beta_n\}$ will be written 
$$[T]_\beta$$
For example, let the matrix
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 6&4&-6\\4&6&-6\\ 6&6&-7 \end{pmatrix}$$
Typically when we write $A$ in this way without any subscripts, we are implying that $A$ is being represented relative to the standard basis, 
$$\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix} \}$$
We can see that the columns of $A$ are just the action of the matrix $A$ on the usual basis vectors. In other words,
$$A \vec{e}_1 = (6,4,6)$$
$$A \vec{e}_2 = (4,6,6)$$
$$A \vec{e}_3 = (-6,-6,-7)$$
The matrix seems to "scramble up" the usual basis vectors. However, with some work (namely, the eigenvalue problem), we can find a different basis
$$\beta = \{\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3\} = \{ \begin{pmatrix} -1\\-2\\-2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -2\\-1\\-2 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 2\\2\\3 \end{pmatrix} \}$$
where
$$A \beta_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 6&4&-6\\4&6&-6\\ 6&6&-7 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1\\-2\\-2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -2\\-2\\-4 \end{pmatrix} = 2 \beta_1$$
Similarly,
$$A \beta_2 = 2 \beta_2 \quad \text{and} \quad A \beta_3 = \beta_3$$
So, the matrix $A$ (which represents some linear transformation) has the representation relative to the basis $\beta$ above
$$[A]_\beta = \begin{pmatrix} 2&0&0\\ 0&2&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
A nice, diagonal matrix! In this case, we can see that $A$ acts by simply lengthening the $\beta$-basis vectors. We may also say that $A$ dilates its eigenspaces.
Hope this helps.

Comment: When we see the notation $[T]_/beta$, here the $/beta$ refers to the basis in the **codomain**, correct? It is just usually the case that this is the same as the basis in the domain. Is this the case?

Comment: The basis beta is generally in the domain, as the matrix A representing T acts (via matrix multiplication) on the beta-vectors. Since A is a square matrix, it is a mapping from R^3 to R^3, so the beta-vectors are both in the domain and range of A.

Comment: Also, A is invertible iff it maps basis vectors to basis vectors